# iOS indexpath.row and indexpath.section

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

So I have a `UITableView` with a contact list set up. All the contacts are broken up into sections based on their first name and ordered alphabetically. I'm trying to get it so people select who they want to add. In my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, when I use indexPath.section or indexPath.row I keep getting the wrong results. Below are the results I get for using .row and .section.

```
Name | Section | Row | Cell index
---------------------------------
Adi  | 0       | 0   | 0
Andy | 0       | 1   | 1
Ben  | 1       | 0   | 2
Jay  | 2       | 0   | 3
Jim  | 2       | 1   | 4
Joe  | 2       | 3   | 5
```

Is there anyway I can get the actual cell index to use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: The only thing that looks wrong is "Joe".  Joe should be section 2, row 2.  Are you sure you noted it correctly?

Comment: How did you setup the datasource? Your code in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? Just do a reverse calcul, or maybe add a index to your cell (custom cells?) and read it.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely correct. The index path contains row indexes range `0...n` PER index section (also range `0...n`).

This allows you to create an array structure like

```
@(@(@"section 0", @"section 0" @"section 0"), @(@"section 1", @"section 1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Set up your data as an array of arrays.  Each element in the top array matches a section and each element in a section array matches a row.

Option 2: Write a method that calculates your cell index for a section and row by adding up all the rows in previous sections and adjusting for the row in the index path.